# Azure cosmos db trigger

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to invoke cosmos db trigger in azure pipeline? Pipeline is just copy data from azrue storage to cosmos db collection and it is necessary to invoke pre trigger. How to specify trigger id for copy activity?

Comment: Are you using Azure Functions? Can you describe what kind of pipeline of events you are using or planning on building? When you say Azure Storage, do you mean Blobs? Queues? Tables?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, Speaking about Azure Storage I mean Blobs. My pipeline just copy dataset form blob to cosmos db. And I know how to invoke trigger for example form Node.js documentdb client api. But I should do it in pipeline.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to save data into Cosmos DB when a Blob is uploaded to Azure Storage? And the information you want to store is the content of the Blob or some of its properties?

Comment: Yes, i think it is necessary to write custom activity for this purpose which will implement trigger business logic.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, you might solve this by using Azure Functions with a [Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) and a [DocumentDB output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb#documentdb-api-output-binding-sample).

With a `functions.json` similar to:

```
{
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings": [
        {
            "name": "myBlob",
            "type": "blobTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "path": "<name-of-the-folder-where-files-get-uploaded>",
            "connection":"MyStorageAccount"
        },
        {
          "name": "documentToSave",
          "type": "documentDB",
          "databaseName": "MyDatabase",
          "collectionName": "MyCollection",
          "createIfNotExists": true,
          "connection": "MyAccount_COSMOSDB",     
          "direction": "out"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the function body could be something like:

```
// Blob trigger binding to a CloudBlockBlob
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static void Run(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, out object documentToSave, TraceWriter log)
{
    // some logic to read the blob and parse it

    documentToSave = new {
        id = "some value",
        .. other properties here
      };
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your clear explanation. But I should to invoke cosmos db pre-trigger when copy pipeline starting. On every copying I should to check if blob document exists it cdb collection and if true replace it. This is cdb pre-trigger business logic. Blob trigger doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Blob trigger will fire whenever you modify/upload a document. The DocumentDB output binding will save or update the document. You have to make sure that the `id` property of the document is correctly set (probably something relative to the document itself, like the name).

Comment: I have an error while trying to copy already existing json to cosmos db collection. I hope to fix this using cosmos db pre-trigger described above.