# Use CosmosDB Database Triggers with Azure Data Factory Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF copy activity copy rows of data from Azure SQL to Azure Cosmos DB.

I have a need to manipulate the document generated. I wrote the logic for the same inside a Pre Create Database Trigger that gets executed whenever a new document is created.

The trigger is not getting executed.

I was not able understand what the problem is, couldn't find any documentation either. The Cosmos DB client API's to create document needs the trigger to execute to be specified explicitly. Not sure if something similar could be done for ADF copy activity as well. Please help.

I am trying to avoid writing a custom activity (so as to leverage built-in scaling and error handling capabilities).

This seems similar to [Azure cosmos db trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057397/azure-cosmos-db-trigger), but the answers are not applicable to this question.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to the [Cosmos DB Database Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#trigger) in the collections or the [Azure Function's Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function)?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta - I am referring to the Cosmos DB database triggers.

Comment: Edited the title to avoid confusion between Triggers :)